# notification with image ios swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, postman, firebase-notifications

I already make notification service extension. and i already follow most tutorial that i can find into this code. but somehow i cannot get the image showing in my ios push notifications. Is there something that i missed ? please help me.

did receive function on my notification service extension is not called. even i already run notification image as the target to my iphone.

this is my payload i tested it through postman.

```
{
   "to": "ekz8YEdjYdc:APA91bFhc0sdnUbVawOlTXJYo1nKMSu3nWoNf7sQ-bv8CWXKJxAheQfJcaujdnmXuASIqRl-Ln3t_3Ax1vDLk5ZuW_naD79TNnoX4SgzykUBPOL_Ia2mklV7iMBjFn2a8QmO_KDkTyTg",

   "notification": {

    "body": "asd",
    "title": "This is test message.",
    "content_available": true,
    "mutable_content": 1
   },

   "data" : {
     "ID" : "12345",
     "TYPE" : "SUMO_POINT_LIST",
     "attachment-url" : "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/email-campaign-s3-bucket/flashdeal27.png"
   }
 }
```

// notification service

```
//  NotificationService.swift
//  NotificationImage
//
//  Created by MacMini4 on 29/12/17.

import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    print("masuk did receive")
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    func failEarly() {
        contentHandler(request.content)
    }

    guard let content = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent) else {
        return failEarly()
    }

    guard let apnsData = content.userInfo["data"] as? [String: Any] else {
        return failEarly()
    }

    guard let attachmentURL = apnsData["attachment-url"] as? String else {
        return failEarly()
    }

    guard let imageData = NSData(contentsOf:NSURL(string: attachmentURL)! as URL) else {
        return failEarly()
    }

    guard let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.create(imageFileIdentifier: "image.gif", data: imageData, options: nil) else {
        return failEarly()
    }

    content.attachments = [attachment]
    contentHandler(content.copy() as! UNNotificationContent)
}

override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}
}

// and already implemented push notifications extension

extension UNNotificationAttachment {
    static func create(imageFileIdentifier: String, data: NSData, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let tmpSubFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let fileURLPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        let tmpSubFolderURL = fileURLPath.appendingPathComponent(tmpSubFolderName, isDirectory: true)
        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: tmpSubFolderURL!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let fileURL = tmpSubFolderURL?.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
            try data.write(to: fileURL!, options: [])
            let imageAttachment = try UNNotificationAttachment.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL!, options: options)
            return imageAttachment
        }
        catch let error {
            print("error \(error)") }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Your notification payload seems incorrect, where is the `aps` key ? Please refer Apple APNS key guideline

Comment: @MidhunMP i am using fcm push notification. not apple push notification